# Convert Json to Object when field name begin with a dot

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, gson

I'm trying to make a conversion from JsonElement to Object using Gson.
The problem is that JsonObject have two fields which the name begins with a dot, and these field are not mapped when I use **gson.fromJson** method.

This is the Json object (a token object):

```
{
   "access_token":"boQtj0SCGz2GFGz[...]",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":1209599,
   "userName":"gonzalo",
   ".issued":"Mon, 14 Oct 2014 06:53:32 GMT",
   ".expires":"Mon, 28 Oct 2014 06:53:32 GMT"
}
```

And this is the target class:

```
private class BearerToken{
        public String access_token;
        public String token_type;
        public String expires_in;
        public String userName;
        public Date issued;
        public Date expires;

        public BearerToken(){
        }
    }
```

This is my code and results:

```
 HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post); // request to server
 String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity()); // json token
 JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
 sonElement jsonElement =  parser.parse(respStr);
 BearerToken token = new BearerToken();             
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 token = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, token.getClass());
```

**respStr:**

```
{"access_token":"d7NDuC7accTA[....]",
"token_type":"bearer",
"expires_in":1209599,
"userName":"43344",
".issued":"Tue, 30 Sep 2014 16:03:17 GMT",
".expires":"Tue, 14 Oct 2014 16:03:17 GMT"}
```

**token:**

[image]

Fields **.expires** and **.issued** are always **null**

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Basically, use `@SerializedName`.

Comment: This is a diferent question. the answer to the question indicated does not work in my case. Please reopen the question to receive new answers. Thanks

Comment: You tried putting `@SerializedName(".expires")` and it didn't work?

Comment: The question is clearly different from the one you mention. The answer can perhaps serve or not, but the question is not a duplicate, is different, and can serve for the people who have the same problem I, to find the answer more quickly.
I'm not a new user on Stackoverflow, and checked first before asking, and not found easily an answer to my problem.

Comment: Your question and the one linked, regardless of their titles, are about how to set custom names for fields. If you have an additional question, consider clarifying it.

Comment: I say again:  That answer didn't work for me! Maybe the null value is caused by another problems. I need help. You can change the title of my question for "custom names" instead "begin with a dot", I do not care, but I need new answers and comments to help me. Please, reopen it.

Comment: Please explain what happened when you added the `@SerializedName`. Your problem is now different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After setting the appropriate `@SerializedName` on the appropriate fields

```
@SerializedName(".expires")
public Date expires;
```

your problem is that Gson doesn't know how to deserialize the JSON date string into a `Date` object.

You'll have to add an appropriate date format.

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");     
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but throw this JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 30 Sep 2014 17:47:14 GMT". com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Tue, 30 Sep 2014 17:55:30 GMT
I don`t know whats is the correct DateFormat

Comment: @Gonzalo You might have to set a different default `Locale` to some English value. `Tue` and `Sep` are English terms.

Comment: @Gonzalo Which Gson version are you using? It seems to use `Locale.US` by default.

Comment: "Tue, 30 Sep 2014 17:47:14 GMT" is returned from a .NET Rest Service.
I'm using gson-2.2.4. How to set a different default Locale for my Android App?

Comment: @Gonzalo That date string works locally. You might want to check if there are any difference's in Android's `SimpleDateFormat`. You can change the default `Locale` with `Locale.setDefault(..)`.

Comment: The correct format is "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss" without "zzz" and   setting default Locale to US. Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis